# PHP to AJAX response failed[object Object]

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble getting an array response from a PHP function into jQuery AJAX. My AJAX is as follows:

```
function getStats() {

    target = $j(event.target);
    parent = $j(target).closest('article');
    property_id = $j(parent).attr('ID').replace('property-','');
    post_id = $j(parent).attr('data-post-id');

    $j.ajax({
        url: ajaxobjects.ajax_url,
       // dataType: 'json',
        data : {
            action : 'getStats',
            property_id: property_id,
            post_id: post_id
        },
        success : function( result ) {
           console.log('success, result is: ' + result + '|')
        },
        error : function( data ) {
           console.log('failed' + result);
        }
    })
}
```

My PHP function is quite lage so I won't paste it all but the key part at the end is:

```
$arr = array(
    'total_this_week' => $total_this_week,
    'total_this_month' => $total_this_month,
    'total_last_month' => $total_last_month,
    'total_this_year' => $total_this_year,
    'total_all_time' => $total_all_time
    );

print json_encode($arr);
```

...which if I leave the `dataType: 'json'` off in the AJAX script gives me the following JSON array in console:

```
{
    "total_this_week": "783",
    "total_this_month": "2341",
    "total_last_month": "7117",
    "total_this_year": "36247",
    "total_all_time": "57792"
}
```

But I can't access it using `result.total_this_week` as I think its just a string. If I switch on dataType to JSON then the console result is `failed[object Object]`.

Confused. What am I doing wrong?

*Update*
I seem to have identified the issue. There is a suffixed 0 at the end of my array but I have no clue where its coming from. I've even totally removed all the function and manually created the array but still the json_encode response to AJAX has the zero at the end as below:

```
`failed{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3,\"d\":4,\"e\":5}0","status":200,"statusText":"parsererror"}`
```

*Solution*
After a few fun hours it was nothing to do with my code, at least not the part I thought. Wordpress apparently adds a zero to admin-ajax.php responses. The solution was to simply add `die();` after echoing the JSON array from PHP.

Comment: The output suggests you're hitting the `error` handler in your AJAX request. Check the network tab of the console after making the request, and note what the HTTP status code is, along with the response text.

Comment: The status code is 200 on and shows correct url/variables e.g `admin-ajax.php?action=getStats&property_id=123456&post_id=78910`. I also just tried `result[0].total_this_week` but that also gives `failed[object Object]`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I get an undefined error if trying `result[0].total_this_week`

Comment: That's because your `result` is an object, not an array. You don't need the index accessor, just `result.total_this_week` should work.

Comment: I think I found the issue but stumped as to what is causing it. I ran the fail result through stringify and there is a 0 at the end of the array. See updated Q.

Comment: @d1ch0t0my your problem is likely unrelated to the php you've provided.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse):

```
...
success : function( result ) {
    console.log('success, result is: ' + JSON.parse(result).total_this_week + '|')
},
...
```

Comment: Or `$.parseJSON(result)....` - and it would be wise to do some defensive checking to see if it's parsed legitimately...

Comment: The better solution would be to simply use `dataType: 'json'` and understand what that does to the result.